# Setting up new OS within current running system

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

I'm planning to buy new drives and reset my entire PC (running Windows 10) and my question is this.
Would it be possible to configure that system in a same way that it's possible within a virtual environment. Basically running the current OS of current drives while configuring the new one on the new drive.

Virtualization can't help since I can't clone that drive and it won't be as good since there might me hardware recognition issues, and cloning current disks isn't an option because I want to start from a completely clean setup with new installations.

While a simple yes or no will do, I'd really appreciate details on why this couldn't work and why it can't be set up.

Thank you and I hope my question was clear enough to understand.

Comment: Simplest might be to just setup a boot USB with the [Installation Media Creation Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/help/15088/windows-create-installation-media). Swap drives, fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

What you're suggesting requires virtualization. Because you don't want to go that route you won't be able to do it. What you can do is prepare folders with installation files and prepare a bootable disk partition so you can install from an HDD instead of some CD/Thumbdrive.

It requires some form of virtualization because you want to execute two instances of an operating system on the same hardware. You could use hardware partitioning for this as well but it's unlikely that your current hardware supports it. Some virtualization solutions also support using a physical disk directly so you might be able to install the OS but as you also mention the HAL might give you some issues depending on your hardware and the solution being used.

Comment: I see. So it would definitely be beneficial to prepare a partition beforehand for all installation features and install the new OS, technically this way I still keep the old data as backup if things go south (as I plan to install the new OS on raid 0 and its my first time doing something like that.